# Slipping shift cable barrel adjusters

Tags: shifter, adjustment

Currently, I have Shimano Tiagra 4600 series brifters on my bike, and the barrel adjuster on the front derailleur cable slips when the shifter/derailleur is in the smallest chainring position, when the cable is at its slackest.

The adjusters appear to be Jagwire Rocket adjusters (see photo), and the cause of the slipping seems to be that the notches on the screw part and base are somewhat different in size and don't engage well enough to prevent the adjuster turning due to road vibration.

I could fix the problem with the existing adjusters by either filing out the notches on the fixed barrel to be slightly larger, or possibly using a mild threadlocker. However, I don't feel that these are good solutions to what appears to be a design flaw with the adjusters (which came with my bike from the factory).

I have a number of questions as to the best fix for this. Should I use the cable adjuster designed by Shimano , subassembly (4) on the [ST-4600 exploded view](http://techdocs.shimano.com/media/techdocs/content/cycle/EV/bikecomponents/ST/EV-ST-4600-3154_v1_m56577569830750055.pdf), which contains an alternative baseplate to place on the shifter itself that provides the indexing and retention of the adjustment.

Alternatively, should I use an inline cable adjuster like the Shimano SM-CA70 (see spread 11/page 20 on the [24 MB 2013 Shimano Spares catalogue](http://bike.shimano.com.br/publish/content/global_cycle/pt/br/index/suporte/download_wosp_2013.html)). I know that these are intended for brifters with under-tape gear cable routing, but are they higher quality than the adjuster that would be built into the Tiagra shifters?

Another option would be adjusters that fit into the downtube cable stops, but my frame (Cannondale Synapse Alloy) has somewhat unusual non-threaded ones mounted on the sides of the head tube, and I fear that the stops being mounted so far forward on the bike would pose an issue with sharp bends for the cable exiting the adjuster if the bars were turned a large angle.

[image: The current adjusters on the bike, it's hard to see but the 'teeth' on the rotating part are too wide to snugly fit in the notches on the fixed part]

Small edit: If I had to summarise the question to be a bit more objective, it is this: do all cable adjusters for the front derailleur cable have issues with slippage due to the lower cable tensions, or are the Jagwire Rocket adjusters just unusually bad at keeping their position? Do either inline or cable stop adjusters generally perform better than the other option?

Comment: How old is the bike?

Comment: It's a 2013 model, bought around the start of this year. I've become quite adept at adjusting the front derailleur if I notice that the adjuster has slipped. I found [a forum post](http://www.bikeforums.net/tandem-cycling/830507-issues-jagwire-inline-cable-adjusters.html#post14592482) that suggests the option of filing the adjuster.

Comment: Is there any slack in the cable when it's in the lowest gear?

Comment: You should be able to take it back to the shop and get them to fix it for you, if you're nice to them.

Comment: @Cole the cable is fairly loose but there's enough tension in the cable that it runs in a straight line between the head tube cable stop and the bottom bracket cable guide, it's certainly not sagging due to gravity or anything. However, this is with the tension adjusted at the barrel adjuster, which is admittedly wound out quite a lot. It might be worth attempting to reattach the cable to the derailleur pinch bolt under more tension, but then what's the point in having a barrel adjuster if I have to make all the adjustments at the pinch bolt anyway?

Comment: @Batman this isn't terribly useful advice, as for one I purchased the bike online (at a noticeable discount), and another, you don't give any indication of what you think the 'fix' might be. Also, I have an academic engineering background and I'm perfectly comfortable working on my bike. The issue really seems to be that the Jagwire adjusters aren't designed well enough to hold their position under a combination of fairly low cable tension (as expected with a triple front derailleur) and normal vibration.

Comment: I'm just thinking if you wound the barrel adjuster in as far as possible, pulled in as much slack in the cable as possible and then readjusted, it would increase the pressure on the barrel adjuster. though it might be the same regardless. did you take the picture? if it's only out that far, then this probably wouldn't do anything. it could also be that the threading in the barrel adjuster is broken, but this happens mostly when the barrel adjuster is a bit further out than the one you have in that photo.

Comment: Also, in my experience, inline barrel adjusters are worse than the rocket adjusters you have. the best are ones on the frame.

Comment: Yes, the photo is mine. The adjuster is wound out around  4 turns in my preferred position, so (since the thread looks like M5) it's effectively moving the clamp position by 0.8 × 4 = 3.2mm, a reasonable adjustment. I'll try increasing the baseline tension tomorrow and seeing if it helps after going for a ride. Could this also possibly be an issue with the length of the outer cable going to the shifter? I would only expect it to manifest with a top-short cable, though and mine certainly isn't at the moment.

Comment: On the quality of adjusters, the Shimano ones available as an option for these specific shifters appear to be similar to those that are usually on rear derailleurs, which I've never had a problem with.

Comment: In support of @Batman, it *is* useful advice. You are not the only person who could have this problem. The principle still holds for online purchases: the vendor has sold something that is not "not fit for purpose". OTOH you got what you paid for.

Comment: Have you tried simply backing out the limit adjustment screw slightly?

Comment: @Daniel Surely I shouldn't have to compromise the adjustment of my derailleur to fix this? The screw is currently set, in line with Shimano's recommendations, such that the inner plate of the FD cage is just barely not touching the chain when the chain is in the smallest chainring, largest cassette sprocket combination.

I've just redone the entire derailleur setup (as per [SI-5MX0A](http://si.shimano.com/php/download.php?file=pdf/um/SI-5MX0A-001-ENG.pdf) and with the cable reattached with as little slack as possible, there's noticeably more tension to hold the adjuster in place.

Comment: Well, from the photo the bumps and notches should be sufficient to hold the adjuster, if there is sufficient cable tension.  Sure seems like the adjustment is off.

Comment: [Here is another photo](http://i.imgur.com/8X71XZa.jpg) that shows the notches a little better, notice that the teeth on the grey   part are rounded and much wider than the notches on the black part, in so much that they barely fit!

Comment: @jbuk from that 2nd photo they look more like detents than (near-)locking stops - I'd expect the notches on the black part to match the teeth on the grey part, as my (flat-bar shimano) adjusters do - a dog clutch would be a bit too extreme.  Putting something (e.g. threadlock) in the thread might work, but I'd be wary of it either going in the wrong place or locking the thread too hard as it's not designed to get a spanner on, also this isn't how it's designed to lock.  Personally I'd file 1 part to match the other - but only after complaining to the store (even online), they might help.

Comment: It's easy to determine if the adjuster is slipping:  After adjusting it the way you want, put a piece of masking tape on it to keep it from moving.  If that fixes the problem then you know what it is (and have a crude fix).

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for posting this problem. I have exactly the same with my Cannondale Synapse alloy 2009 (Tiagra triple). During every ride I have to tighten the micro-adjuster. After renewing cables, housings, bottom bracket guide etc several times I have finally reached the conclusion it's the barrel adjuster itself.

Answer (score 1):

I work in a volume dealership bike shop.  One of the top in the country.  I rarely, if ever, have seen this problem.  The cable should not be slack when in low gear.  Take it to your LBS.

Comment: Welcome to [bicycles.se] @Ian. When you say *One of the top in the country*, which country would that be?